# Why does mysql_fetch_field exhaust memory in this query?

Tags: php, mysql

My query is a couple of left joins over three tables. The number of rows returned is 30k. The rows are pretty big.

The query executes fine (as in mysql_query($sql) doesn't cause errors).

If I loop through this query with while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){} there is no problem. However, before the while loop I do this:

```
$types = array();
while($field = mysql_fetch_field($result)){

    switch($field->type) {
         case "int":
                $types[$field->name] = 'int';
                break;
         case "real":
            $types[$field->name] = 'float';
            break;
        default:
            $types[$field->name] = 'string';
            break;
    }
}
```

And php throws a **fatal error** at the `mysql_fetch_field` line:

> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 24 bytes)

Why is this, why doesn't the `mysql_fetch_array` while loop cause a memory issue too? And how can I use `mysql_fetch_field` to get the field name types.

Comment: You shouldn't be using the `mysql_*` functions anyway. They have been deprecated for a long time. Use mysqli or PDO.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the mysql_fetch_field with offset

```
$types = array();
$index=0;
$num_fields=mysql_num_fields($resource);

while($index<$num_fields) {
 $field=mysql_fetch_field($resource, $index);



    switch($field->type) {
         case "int":
                $types[$field->name] = 'int';
                break;
         case "real":
            $types[$field->name] = 'float';
            break;
        default:
            $types[$field->name] = 'string';
            break;
    }
 $index++; 
}
```

Comment: It shouldn't matter because if no index is provided, the function automatically fetches the next unfetched field. http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-field.php

Comment: i suspect that name of the field could be like an expression that engine try to execute or something similar, that is why it fails. when iterate it like an array with index it's different

Comment: how is it different? You are still getting an object back either way.

Comment: i think that there is a difference in an internal C++ implementation, Are the manes of the fields simple words?

Comment: This still gives the same error, on this line: field=mysql_fetch_field($resource, $index);

Comment: well can you post a query?

Comment: Hi, I created the test environment. 50K rows and 49 fields. I had no problems. It should be related to the query itself and field names